# How to index special characters in sphinx

Tags: indexing, special-characters, search-engine, sphinx

I have some special characters (e.g #) between my text and I don't want that these character treated as separators. I have added these characters to charset_table:

```
charset_table = 0..9, english, _, #
```

I also used this format (U+23) but it didn't work. How can I index this characters?

Comment: `U+23` should work just fine. Did you recreate your index after you changed its config?

Comment: Also maybe elaborate on 'didnt work'. How checking it it 'worked'? Guessing running a test query. Check 'SHOW META' to see how the query is tokenized, and how many matches each keyword have.

Comment: @hank yes, I recreated index after changing.